# Fredholm equation with symmetric kernel

Tags: integral-equations

I have the following equation : 
$$
\phi(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\pi^2}{4}\int_{0}^{1}K(x,t)\phi(t)dt
$$

where 
$$
K(x,t)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{x(2-t)}{2}  & \mbox{if } 0 \leq x \leq t \\
  \frac{t(2-x)}{2} & \mbox{if } t \leq x \leq1
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

I tried differentiating twice to try and find the eigenfucntions of the homogenic equation but the ode is too hard to solve and I can't get a sturm liueville condition properly because phi on 0 is 0 but I there is not second condition.

** Edit : The question was made much simpler when a small change was made; probably due to a mistake in the exam that this question was taken out of.

Comment: The kernel should be, right? $$
K(x,t)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{x(2-t)}{2}  & \mbox{if } 0 \leq x \leq t \\
  \frac{t(\color{red}{2-x})}{2} & \mbox{if } t \leq x \leq1
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Most probably yeah, so there is a mistake in the exam form I took the question from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the correct Kernel is what I mentioned in the comment above - given that you mentioned about symmetry - then differenting twice we obtain $$\phi''(x)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\phi(x)=0.$$Now this is standard, knowing that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi'(1)+\phi(1)=\frac12$.

Comment: Well you are probably right, I got that question from an exam that took place a few years ago so I can't really ask anyone if that is a mistake.. so it is not just my mistake - this is indeed a nearly unsolvable question as posed. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome :-)